# Why fseek does not return a position here, but just redirecting fread to a specific record?

Tags: c, file, binary, fread, fseek

So i basically have a binary input folder containing some students and their information. And i don't understand some things regarding the fseek and fread there after "while" function. After i run it, and type a key to search for a student, it prints the student associated with that key instead of the one on that position (dimension in bytes from the origin as offset). And i want to know why, in order to use the information to my project, as this program is a kind of tutorial from the professor. Thank you in advance!

*EDIT ( Second program is my attempt for the project, but with cars. Its output is the car on position "chooseKey" and not with "chooseKey" as an atribute, as the first program. And i don t know what i did wrong.)

```
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include <conio.h> 

typedef struct { 

                 int nrm;             
                 char CNP[14];         
                 char nume[30];      
                 int an;              
                 int grupa;           
                 unsigned char note[20];  
                 char is;
               } STUDENT;

int filesize(FILE* f, int rec_size)
{
  long crt_pos;
  int size;

  crt_pos = ftell(f);  
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) ;    
  size=ftell(f) / rec_size;  
  fseek(f, crt_pos, SEEK_SET); 
  return size; 

}

void main()
{ char numefr[30] = "Studenti_r_f.dat";
  FILE* f;
  STUDENT x;
  int key, dim;

  fopen_s(&f, numefr, "rb+");
  dim=filesize(f, sizeof(STUDENT)); 

  printf_s("Enrollment number: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &key);
  while(key != 0)
  {
    //check key range
    if(key >= dim)
      printf_s("\nThere is no student with this enrollment number. Try again?");
    else
    {
      //check if valid key
      fseek(f, key*sizeof(STUDENT), SEEK_SET);
      fread(&x, sizeof(STUDENT), 1, f);
      if(x.is == 0)
        printf("\nThere is no student with this enrollment number. Try again?");
      else
        printf_s("\nStudent: %s, Year: %d, Group: %d, ATP grade: %d\n",x.nume,x.an,x.grupa,x.note[5]);
    }
    printf_s("\n\nEnrollment number (or 0): ");
    scanf_s("%d", &key);
  }

 fclose(f);

 printf("\nDone. Press a key.",numefr);
 _getch();
}
```

````
typedef struct {
    int key;
    char color[20];
    int price;
    char brand[15];
}CAR ;

int sizeOfFile(FILE* inBinFile, int sizeOfRecord)
{
    long currentPosition;
    int size;

    currentPosition = ftell(inBinFile);
    fseek(inBinFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(inBinFile) / sizeOfRecord;
    fseek(inBinFile, currentPosition, SEEK_SET);
    return size;
}
void main()
{
    FILE * inBinFile;
    CAR var;
    int chooseKey, fileDim;

    printf_s("Type a key to identify a car..."); // 20 records in the file
    scanf_s("%d", &chooseKey); 

    fopen_s(&inBinFile, "Machines.bin", "rb+");
    fileDim = sizeOfFile(inBinFile, sizeof(CAR));

    while (chooseKey != -1)
    {
        if (chooseKey >= fileDim)
            printf_s("\nNo car with key %d found. Retry.", chooseKey);
        else
        {
            fseek(inBinFile, chooseKey*sizeof(CAR), SEEK_SET);
            fread(&var, sizeof(CAR), 1, inBinFile);
            printf_s("\nThe %d key indicates to the %s car coloured in %s which cost %d dollars", chooseKey, var.brand, var.color, var.price);
        }
        printf_s("\n\n\nTo search for another car enter a key, or hit 1 and enter to stop: ");
        scanf("%d", &chooseKey);
    }
    fclose(inBinFile);
    printf_s("\nAlright. Press any key...");
    _getch();
}   ```
````

Comment: `fclose(stdin);` wow! First time I see this!! To OP: you didn't open the `stdin`; don't close it, it's not your responsability.

Comment: As i said, i try to use this source to make my own project, i don't understand certain things that he wrote there, especially the ones that i mentioned in title :)

Comment: What do you think is the result of `key * sizeof(STUDE T)`? (If you can't work it out, try using a debugger.)

Comment: When you enter a `key` of 1, you're reading the _second_ record from the file (the first, with key 0, is unreadable since you use 0 to end the program).

Comment: I have used debugger but all i can see is the value entering the variable, and i don't know why that value is the same as its "nrm" value and gets to be displayed by that in the end.

Comment: The very very first student is in position `0`, which is your signal to end the program. I suggest you accept `0` as a valid key and use `-1` as a signal.

Comment: Regarding the ending of the program, even if i change the condition, its output is still in the same form. But your answer is close to my attempt for the project. I created a bin file with cars giving them relative unique keys from 10 to 29. When i implement this algorithm that i wrote. Mine displays the car on that position and not with that key as an atribute.

Comment: I have posted my personal program that i've been trying to do as same as the first. I want to know what is the difference between them, in order to understand why the output is so different from one to another.